# How to design an Hierarchial private domain including Top level domains using bind

Tags: networking

How to design an Hierarchial private domain including Top level domains using bind..for example there should be a root . and then it should have details to xxx. and the xxx. TLD should have the address to another subdomain yyy.xxx ...How to establish this hierarchy in bind..?

Answer (score 0):

The root zone is by default a *hint* [type zone](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/zone.html#type):

> The initial set of root-servers is defined using a hint zone. When the
>   server starts up it uses the hints zone file to find a root name
>   server and get the most recent list of root name servers. If no hint
>   zone is specified for class IN, the server uses a compiled-in default
>   set of root servers. Classes other than IN have no built-in defaults
>   hints. 'hint' zone files are covered in more detail under required
>   zones.

In BIND configuration this is something like:

```
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};
```

However, a hint zone is only [required](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/index.html#required) if the server supports recursize queries. To achieve your goal:

1. Disable recursion with `recursion no;` in `options {}`.
2. Replace the hint `zone "."` with a `type master;` zone.
3. Have all the subdomains directly within this zone on delegate control to sub-zones.
4. ???
5. Profit.